# Nth Child Last child where Odd

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm working on a blog theme, currently I have a post which has multiple images however the client wants them to be in a grid format so I did:

```
.photoset img{
    display: block;
    width:50%
    float: left;
}
```

This works fine however when there are an odd number of images 
this doesn't work obviously.

How would I do a selector for the last child where odd?
So I can then

```
[lastchildwhereodd]{
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine both `:nth-child(odd)` and `:last-child` together:

```
.photoset img:nth-child(odd):last-child
```

Note that while `:nth-last-child()` is also available, it's not the right selector to use here because it counts backwards, which means `:nth-last-child(odd)` will *always* match `:last-child` regardless of whether there is an odd or even number of children.

Note also that the `display: block` declaration isn't necessary in either case because floating elements are always `display: block`.

Comment: Thank you Bolt. I appreciate you taking the time to explain things to me instead of just placing some code there. It really helps.

Also, the code you provided didn't work but it put me on the right track.

The :last-child selector wouldn't work on an img cannot have children (I'm presuming).

However I found the :last-of-type selector work perfectly.

Modified code;
.photoset img:nth-child(odd):last-of-type{
   width: 100%;
}

Worked beautifully, thanks for you help and time.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz: In that case, it simply means that there are other children after your last img preventing that last img from qualifying as the "last child". That an img cannot have children is unrelated - `:last-child` and `:last-of-type` work similarly except the latter considers the element type (img, div, span, etc).